# Root Debug FS doesn't work

Tags: root-access

Whenever I run Root Debug FS for my Samsung Galaxy Stellar (4.1.2 jb, Model # SCH-I200, baseband I200VRBME1), I get this error:

[image]

ADB.exe is an application in the same folder as the batch file, but it says it won't run. When I run ADB.exe it just flashes the commnad line and goes away after writing out a ton of text (it dissapears too quickly for me to read it)

Comment: Running `adb` without parameters causes it just to show its "help page". Please try the following: Open a command shell, change to the directory `adb.exe` and your batch file are in, and try running the batch file from there. My guess is that directory is not in your `%PATH%`, and thus the batch cannot find `adb.exe` when executed "from elsewhere".

Comment: Glad to read! I made it a full answer for you to accept then, listing up the other possibilities along. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out: with `adb.exe` not being in the `%PATH%` (or `$PATH` for Linux/Mac users), the batch file was not able to find it. So there are 3 solutions to it:

1. fixing the batch file to look in the very same directory
2. fixing the `%PATH%`/`$PATH` to include the directory
3. changing into the directory the batch (and ADB) files are located in, and running it from there

For a one-time run, #3 is the easiest approach:

- open a command shell (on Windows via the start menu, open a `cmd` – on Linux via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering e.g. `xterm`)
- change to the directory (using the `cd` command with the directory as argument; on Windows, you might need to switch to the correct drive letter before)
- run the batch/shell script from there

If you need that script more often, it might be worth trying one of the other two approaches. Not being a Windows user, I don't know where exactly to add the `PATH` information there (AFAIR it was in "Environment variables" somewhere in the settings of the control center); on Linux you can just do so in your `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`, adding a line like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/where/is/adb
```

(of course using the correct path instead of `/where/is/adb`).

Fixing the script/batch is a little beyond the scope of our site :)